# Using forms to change CSS

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

What I am trying to do is create a CMS using PHP and AJAX. I'm trying to create a form that'll change css for the whole website.

Is it possible to store a php variable or will I need to use a database to achieve this?

PHP/CSS code

```
$bgcolour = $_POST['bgColour'];
?>

body {
background-color:<?php echo $bgcolour; ?>;
}
```

AJAX CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#css').on('submit',function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url:'../css/style.php',
        data:$(css).serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){
            $('<style type="text/css"></style>')
             html(css)
  .         appendTo("head");
            console.log(data);
            if(data != "Error") {
               $("#data").html(data).show().fadeOut(9000);
            }
            else {
               $("#data").html(data).show().fadeOut(9000);
            }
        },
        error:function(data){
            $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("css").reset();
    $("#main").load(location.href + " #main");
});
});
```

HTML Code

```
<h2>Change Website Style</h2>
<form name="css" id="css" action="">
Background Colour: <input type="text" name="bgColour" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="css" /></form>
```

Comment: You'll need to store it in the database if you want it to out live the session. You also probably don't want them to redownload the style every time they make a change. You could change the styles that already exists though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends really, I agree with @DanielM - you will need to store this information in a database if you want these settings to carry throughout the users' session.

Another option is to use the session super global `$_SESSION` to store that information. However, once the user leaves your site - the site will revert back to the "default" background color.

If you are going to use some sort of authentication; meaning the user logs in, and then sets the background color. Database is the way to go. That way when the page loads, you can write a php script to get/set the color they entered.

If you just want an anonymous user to enter a color and don't care that it goes away when they leave, you might get away using `$_SESSION`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'm already using a database so I'll go that route. How would I go about setting the values from pdo to the css?

Comment: Depends I guess. You could either echo out the style right on the page, or give your background a generic class like `.bkg-color`. Then, if the user sets a value (choses a color) you can have php set the value in the db to `#cccccc` (for example). Then when the page loads, php can check for that. If there is a value, assign the `.bkg-color` class to your body element. If they haven't selected a color, don't assign the class.